# Show that : $ h(A, B) = \sup_{x^*\in D} |s(x^*|A)-s(x^*|B)| $

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Let $(X,\|.\|)$ be a separable Banach space with dual $X^*$. $\mathcal{P}_{wkc}(X)$ be the class of nonempty, weakly-compact and convex subsets of $X$. For any $C\in\mathcal{P}_{wkc}(X)$  we define its support function $s(.|C):X^*\to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ by:
$$
s(x^*|C):=\sup_{x\in C} \langle x^*,x \rangle\qquad \forall x^*\in X^*
$$
and its radius by :

$$
\|C\|:=\sup_{x\in C}\|x\|
$$

then :
$$
s(x^*|C)\le \|x^*\|\|C\|\qquad \forall x^*\in X^*
$$

We define the hausdorff distance $h$ on $\mathcal{P}_{wkc}(X)$ by : let $A,B\in \mathcal{P}_{wkc}$ :
$$
h(A, B) = \sup_{\|x^*\|\leq 1} |s(x^*|A)-s(x^*|B)|
$$
We shall denote by $\tau$ the ***Mackey topology*** on the dual space $X^*$ such that :

> $$
> x_n^*\overset{\tau}{\longrightarrow} x^* \Longleftrightarrow \forall C\in \mathcal{P}_{wkc}~:~\sup_{x\in C}{\langle x_n^*-x^*,x\rangle}\to 0
> $$

Let $D\subset X^*$ be a subset $\tau$-dense in unit ball of $X^*$ $\big(\{x^*\in X^*~:~\|x^* \|\le 1\}\big)$.

Show that :
$$
h(A, B) = \sup_{x^*\in D} |s(x^*|A)-s(x^*|B)|
$$
An idea please.